# Bug in Google Wallet / Android Pay sample app when using WalletFragmentStyle?

Tags: android, android-pay

I am developing a mobile android app. I'm using the sample github app for Android Pay/Google Wallet.

One issue I found during the product checkout page, is the following. If I use the following API:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragmentStyle.LogoImageType

This changes the logo ("Google Wallet" vs "Android Pay" logos). 
When using a value of 3 as a parameter for **setMaskedWalletDetailsLogoImageType(3)**, the "Change" button no longer becomes functional.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Android wallet is deprecated, in my case i did this;**

 1. check id the device have NFC support (android pay use NFC)
 2. if have nfc support use android pay, if dont have i use android wallet.

**First in the constant.java add:**
<br/>

    //values to change buyapparence (android pay-wallet)
    public static final int GOOGLE_WALLET_CLASSIC=1;
    public static final int GOOGLE_WALLET_GRAYSCALE =2;
    public static final int GOOGLE_WALLET_MONOCHROME=3;
    public static final int ANDROID_PAY_DARK = 4;
    public static final int ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT=5;
    public static final int ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT_WITH_BORDER=6;
**Then in utils add the NFCcheck.java with this method;**
<code>
    public boolean NFCsupport(){
        boolean nfcSupport;
        NfcManager manager = (NfcManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
        NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {
             nfcSupport=true;
            //Yes NFC available
        }else{
            nfcSupport=false;
            //Your device doesn't support NFC
        }
        return nfcSupport;
    }
</code>
**Then in your Checkout.java or when you have wallet implemention add this;**
<code>
if(nfcController.NFCsupport()){
            //turn on nfc
            nfcController.enableNfcPower(true);
            //show nfc payment(android pay)
            mWALLET_APPEARANCE=Constants.ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT;
            createAndAddWalletFragment(mWALLET_APPEARANCE);
            Log.d("nfc", "you have nfc support");
        }else{
            Log.d("nfc", "dont have nfc support");
            //show not nfc payment(wallet)
            mWALLET_APPEARANCE=Constants.GOOGLE_WALLET_CLASSIC;
            createAndAddWalletFragment(mWALLET_APPEARANCE);
        }
</code>
**in your createAndAddWalletFragment(int WALLET_APPEARANCE) change the appearance flags;**
<code>

    WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
    .setBuyButtonText(BuyButtonText.BUY_WITH_GOOGLE)
    .setBuyButtonAppearance(WALLET_APPEARANCE)
    .setBuyButtonWidth(WalletFragmentStyle.Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);
    </code>

**Second, sent the wallet_appareance in the intent;**<br/>
<code>
        intent.putExtra("wallet_appearance",mWALLET_APPEARANCE);
</code>
**and in your confirmationActivity update this funcion to listen the event with the logo correctly in the createAndAddWalletFragment();**
<code>
 WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
        .setMaskedWalletDetailsLogoImageType(mWALLET_APPEARANCE)//from getintent
        .setMaskedWalletDetailsTextAppearance(
                R.style.BikestoreWalletFragmentDetailsTextAppearance)
                .setMaskedWalletDetailsHeaderTextAppearance(
                        R.style.BikestoreWalletFragmentDetailsHeaderTextAppearance)
                .setMaskedWalletDetailsBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.white))
                .setMaskedWalletDetailsButtonBackgroundResource(
                        R.drawable.bikestore_btn_default_holo_light);
</code>
finally in your fullWalletconfirmationbutton.java in the onCreate method dont forget the function useGoogleWallet to create and setup the fragment;
<code>
 // Set up an API client;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .setAccountName(accountName)
                .addApi(Wallet.API, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                        .useGoogleWallet()
                        .setEnvironment(Constants.WALLET_ENVIRONMENT)
                        .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
                        .build())
                .build();
</code>
**and you have android pay and android wallet support.**
```